# Is it possible to configure the kubernetes api server address when using traefik?

Tags: kubernetes, traefik

Today I found the Traefik could not forward the http request with the slave node(the slave node also edge node that could recieve http request from external internet), when I using this command to send http request to Traefik service(the traefik was listening on the host's 8000 port):

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:8000 --header "Host:read.example.top"
```

shows 404 page not found. then I checked traefik (version 2.10) pod log output I found an error log like this:

```
"Objects listed" error:Get "https://10.0.0.1:443/apis/traefik.io/v1alpha1/ingressrouteudps?limit=500&resourceVersion=0": dial tcp 10.0.0.1:443: i/o timeout 30001ms (12:15:13.434)
Trace[44198543]: [30.001185993s] [30.001185993s] END
```

From this error message I can know there is some problem with treafik to communicate with the kuberentes api service. Is it possible to configure the kubernetes api server address when using traefik?

Comment: Are there any other details you can provide so people can understand what you're trying to do?